# For how many natural pairs $(a,b)$ that $1 \le a,b \le 10$ the equation $x^2=ax-b$ has a solution in $[0,1]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For how many natural pairs $(a,b)$ that $1 \le a,b \le 10$ the equation $x^2=ax-b$ has a solution in $[0,1]$?

**My attempt**:We have:

$x=\frac{x^2+b}{a}$

So if we have such root we should have:

$0 \le x^2+b \le a$

It can be easily proved that we don't have $a,b$ that $x=0$ so we have:

$1 \le b < a$

If we have just this condition we'll have $45$ pairs.The answer in the book is $45$ too but I can't prove this condition is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that $1\le b<a$ is *necessary.*
It only remains to show that thiscondition also is *sufficient.*
Consider $f(x)=x^2-ax+b$ where $1\le b\le a-1$. Then $f(0)=b>0$ and $f(1)=1-a+b\le 0$ so that we either have a root at $1$ or the Intermediate Value Theorem gives us a root in $(0,1)$.